# How do i take the sigmoid of all the records of a column in a dataset in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, logistic-regression

I wanted to take the sigmoid of a column in my data set.

I have defined a function for the same

```
import math

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
```

but how do i give all the values of the column in one time?

Comment: You either need to use the apply method, or better as a vector: `df['new_col'] = sigmoid(def['col'])` but then replace math.exp with numpy.exp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply`, but it is not vecorized solution. Better/faster way is use `np.exp` for vecorized approach.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 40, -6, 1, 0, -1, -60, 100, 0.2, 0.004, -0.0053]})

import math

def sigmoid(x): 
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

df['s1'] = df.A.apply(sigmoid)
df['s2'] = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-df.A))
print (df)
           A            s1            s2
0    10.0000  9.999546e-01  9.999546e-01
1    40.0000  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
2    -6.0000  2.472623e-03  2.472623e-03
3     1.0000  7.310586e-01  7.310586e-01
4     0.0000  5.000000e-01  5.000000e-01
5    -1.0000  2.689414e-01  2.689414e-01
6   -60.0000  8.756511e-27  8.756511e-27
7   100.0000  1.000000e+00  1.000000e+00
8     0.2000  5.498340e-01  5.498340e-01
9     0.0040  5.010000e-01  5.010000e-01
10   -0.0053  4.986750e-01  4.986750e-01
```

---

```
#110 k rows
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [10, 40, -6, 1, 0, -1, -60, 100, 0.2, 0.004, -0.0053] * 10000})


In [15]: %timeit df['s1'] = df.A.apply(sigmoid)
57.4 ms ± 6.78 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [16]: %timeit df['s2'] = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-df.A)) 
2.64 ms ± 81.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```